Spring Integration: META-INF/spring.integration.properties file not being recognized in Spring Boot application
According to

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/context/IntegrationProperties.html and
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/8704

I should be able to override the defaultTimeout by setting spring.integration.endpoints.defaultTimeout=-1 inside META-INF/spring.integration.properties
However, even after doing that, upon starting my Spring Boot application, the log still reads:
23:24:25.076 DEBUG [main] o.s.i.c.IntegrationConfigurationReport: 
Spring Integration global properties:

spring.integration.channels.autoCreate=true
spring.integration.channels.error.requireSubscribers=true
spring.integration.taskScheduler.poolSize=10
spring.integration.readOnly.headers=
spring.integration.channels.maxUnicastSubscribers=2147483647
spring.integration.endpoints.noAutoStartup=
spring.integration.channels.error.ignoreFailures=true
spring.integration.messagingTemplate.throwExceptionOnLateReply=false
spring.integration.channels.maxBroadcastSubscribers=2147483647
spring.integration.endpoints.defaultTimeout=30000

and my application seems broken (presumably because of the 30 second default timeout).
How can I get my application to recognize this property ?
PS: My .jar file includes META-INF/spring.integration.properties and the following manages to read the file
try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/spring.integration.properties")) {


I'm using
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

which in turn uses
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

